# How to convert a json into base64 string in jsonnet

Tags: json, jsonnet

I have a `json` file. I want to encode into `base64` string and add it in my main `json` using [jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/).

`datasources.json`:

```
{
  "datasources": [{
    "id": 1,
    "orgId": 1,
    "name": "prometheus"
  }]
}
```

`grafana.jsonnet`:

```
local getDataSources() = {
    'datasources': (import 'datasources.json').datasources,
};

local kp = {
    dashboardDatasources+: {
       data: std.base64(getDataSources().datasources),
    }
}
kp
```

Please suggest how to get this done. Struggling to convert `json` into a string in `jsonnet`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using [std.manifestJsonEx](https://jsonnet.org/ref/stdlib.html)

> std.manifestJsonEx(value, indent) Convert the given object to a JSON
>   form. indent is a string containing one or more whitespaces that are
>   used for indentation:

Here is the solution:

```
local getDataSources() = {
    'datasources': (import 'datasources.json').datasources,
};

local dataSources = getDataSources().datasources;

local kp = {
    dashboardDatasources+: {
       data: std.base64(std.manifestJsonEx(dataSources, " ")),
    }
}
kp
```